# Override font size for 3.5 inch iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uitextfield

I'm subclassing `UILabel` and `UITextField` in order to change the font size on just 3.5 inch devices (as this can't be done using size classes independently of 4 and 4.7 inch devices).

The font changes if it's done in `layoutSubviews()` but it's repeatedly called so the font size ends up at zero. I'm trying to find another place to set it that is only called once and still can override the font size.

Code:

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .Portrait) {
    if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height < 568) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Score Board", size: (self.font.pointSize - CGFloat(10.0)))
    } else {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Score Board", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
} else {
    if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 568) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Score Board", size: (self.font.pointSize - CGFloat(10.0)))
    } else {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Score Board", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

I've also tried it in `didMoveToSuperview()` and `willMovetoSuperview()`, it was only called once but it didn't actually change the fonts. I've also tried it in `init` but again the font isn't set.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomUILabel : UILabel {

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        // Code from above
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that you have this code placed in a method that gets called over and over,  something like this should only exist in the view load and did orientation change methods

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't think there is a viewDidLoad, it's a subclass of a `UITextField` and a `UILabel`... are there any functions you know of that are only called once I could do this in?

Comment: yes, did you try overriding init?,  also you can use willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon doesn't work in there, fonts aren't being changed

Comment: if it doesnt work in the will move, that means the font is being set after, so try it in the didmovetosuperview

Comment: didMoveToSuperview was a no go too

Comment: I can't seem to override `init` as it tells me it `Expected identifier in function declaration`

Comment: Not sure what you are typing, but this is how you override those init if you are using ViewBuilder,  required init?(coder: aDecoder: NSCoder){super.init(coder:aDecoder); ... //other code }

Comment: Yeah, i figured out what i was doing wrong but it doesn't appear to ever be called

Comment: what?  are you using viewbuilder?  did you set the UITextField to the class you are doing these overrides in

Comment: Ok init?(coder:) is being called but it doesn't affect the font

Comment: I'll post my whole subclass

Comment: ok well like I said earlier lol the font must be set after the willmovetosuperview, so instead use didmovetosuperview

Comment: The font is not changed in didMoveToSuperview either.

Comment: I am missing something on your end then, I just did a font change on init willmove and didmove,  all changed the font.  Are you sure you are using the iPhone 4s simulator

Comment: @Knight0fDragon did you try using my code i posted above? I'm certain it's the 4s simulator.

Comment: yes, I did it in my own project,  works fine right in the init.  do a print(self.font.pointSize) before and after you change the font, you will see it works.  Something else is changing your font size

Comment: My labels/text fields are all set with text/size in interface builder, then i'm trying to override it in code. I can see the value changes but by the time the value changes, the font is already displayed

Comment: if you change the value in the init?  that is impossible

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i think in the case of init, it's setting it, then it's being overwritten by IB

Comment: IB does not overwrite it.  If you create a new project, you will see the code works.  Do you by chance have autoshrink on?  Not sure what else you could be calling that will reset the font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `didSet` for the `font` property.

```
class MyLabel : UILabel {

    private func shouldShrinkFont() -> Bool {
        let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        // This check works regardless of orientation.
        return size.width + size.height == 480 + 320
    }

    override var font: UIFont! {
        didSet {
            if shouldShrinkFont() {
                super.font = UIFont(name: "Score Board", size: font.pointSize - 10)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I do the same for a UITextField subclass? I'm subclassing both... I don't understand why apple can't just give us a size class for 3.5 inch devices.....

Comment: I'm getting an error - : `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in my UILabel subclass

Comment: I updated my answer. It looks like you have to say `super.font = ...` in `didSet` or you get infinite recursion.